# UITableViewCell's layer not getting updated after heightForRowAt IndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cagradientlayer, heightforrowatindexpath

I am changing the size of each TableViewCell with:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}
```

Then, within the custom cell class, I am inserting a 'gradientLayer' as a sublayer to the Cell's layer property:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    ...
    gradientLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    ...
}
```

However, the gradient is not filling up the whole cell:
[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening/how I can fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you use a plain `UITableViewCell` :**

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        // ...

        let gradient =  CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = cell.contentView.frame
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        cell.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

        // ...

        return cell
    }
```

You need to make sure that you're adding the gradient to the contentView's layer.

And this would work just fine.

**If you use a custom `UITableViewCell` class :**

Now, if you are using a custom cell class, you will need to **override the `layoutSubviews()` method** like so :

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    gradient.frame = contentView.frame
}
```

This ensures that your gradient frame is always equal to your contentView frame at anytime.

Your custom cell class would then look like this:

```
class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    lazy var gradient : CAGradientLayer = {
        var gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        return gradient
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // ...

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // ...

        gradient.frame = contentView.frame

        // ...

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // ...
    }


}
```

Just let me know if you have any additional questions !

Comment: Setting the frame in init is not correct. The frame at that point will be the default frame for the cell, which may not be what heightForRowAtIndexPath is returning.

Comment: Which is why I said to the OP to set in layoutSubviews() !

Comment: Please don't mind my copy/paste mistake though, I updated the answer :).

Comment: The init code you're showing is incorrect in both cases. That's my point. The frame should never be used from there because heightForRowAtIndexPath hasn't been applied yet.

Comment: It's not incorrect at all, at the time cellForRow() method is called, your cell DOES have a height, and its frame is set, if you would like to make sure please do so with a sample project.

Comment: The only place where it isn't set just yet, is the init method (where the frame is indeed CGRect.zero) and that's why the OP problem is happening here. He needs to set the frame in layoutSubviews() method so that the gradient can fill the contentView's frame properly.

Comment: Ah, it's changed now. Ok. I'd subclass the cell in the first case rather than put the cell's gradient adding code in the tableview class's cellForRow, but that's me. Both would work.

Comment: the height at init is for sure not the heightForRowAtIndexPath height. That can't be set until the cell is created, and you're in init.

Comment: Exactly. Both would work just fine. I just wanted to show the OP two use cases. One with a plain UITableViewCell, and the other solution, that uses a custom class for the UITableViewCells, and I think my answer makes it very clear.

Comment: I am not talking about the cell height at init,  but rather about the cell height inside the cellForRow method. And this does reflect the height you set in the heightForRow method. In the init though, obviously it would return CGRect.zero because the methods haven't been called just yet.

Comment: It's not zero, it's the default cell rect. My comments on that originally were about the code you changed. There's another problem with the "UITableViewCell" case. in cellForRowAtIndexPath, the height from heightForRowAtIndexPath has not been applied. I just verified. So, the frame you're setting there is also happening at the wrong time. It should be done in layoutSubviews in a cell subclass, or in the storyboard itself without heightForRowAtIndexPath, which won't work if you need to set it dynamically or have different height cells with the same reuse identifier.

Comment: I hate to say it, but @clarus, you would better check by yourself before saying wrong information. In the cellForRow method, the cell height from rowHeight method HAS been applied, just try setting the height in your method to 200 (which is not the default height), and check with a print(cell.contentView.frame) in your cellForRow method. What does this return? Yes, right, it returns (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 199.666666666667).

Comment: As I mentioned, I did check and it sure wasn't. It was wrong in the cell's init, it was wrong in the initial cellForTableView after the cell was returned, and it was only correct in layoutSubviews. Are you sure you're not checking a dequeued cell that was already created, not fresh from init? Because that will obviously have already been set. Either way, it's poor form to be setting sublayers or subviews, or any display details of a cell outside of the cell class. The layout code for the cell should be contained within the cell class it applies to.

Comment: @clarus, from the start of our conversation, I am talking about the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, and obviously, this method doesn't live inside your custom cell class, but rather in your view controller. So I am not talking about the init method here. You seem to be confused with the init() method, which of course, as I already said long ago, would definitely return CGRect.zero.

Comment: Ok this is getting too long so I'm dropping off. The code in your first example that adds your cell's layers in your cellForRowAtIndexPath should be in the cell. It's poor design otherwise.. That's what I'm saying, and It's pretty clear. And, no, init for the cell does not have a frame of zerorect. Check it. I did to make sure. Its set to the default size when super init is called. Anyway, last one from me. Peace.

Comment: 1: This is precisely why I gave the OP two possibilities. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are not the OP. He can choose whichever he likes the most. 2: I am talking about the cell content view's frame, not the cell's frame itself. 3: Thanks, good luck anyway !

Comment: This worked for me and I believe it is the correct option for me since I am using a custom cell. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that @Mike ! Good luck on your project then :)

Comment: This is wrong you are adding layer inside dequeue method. The dequeue method is used when you want configure based on data. But problem here is it will create multiple gradient layers and add multiple times..will surely slow down the scrolling speed.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it happening? I don't know.

But if you put the gradient inside your tableview's `cellForRowAt`, you get:

[image]

---

Here's the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height)
    cell.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Exactly, and this is what I am trying to explain to @clarus. At the time your cellForRow method is called, your heightForRow already run, hence you can set the gradient frame in this method without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The frame size at init time is the default frame of your cell, from the storyboard or wherever. It won't have your height of 60 (unless that matches) because the cell is just being created in init and *then* it will be resized.

You can add the layer there, but do the resizing in layoutSubviews or use constraints to autolayout. If you do that, the gradient will fill your cell at its final size.